# Android Project uploading to Google Play store - Limited package name issue

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I coded an android application in Eclipse, and I want to upload that to the Google Play store now. How ever, when I select my APK-file, it says: You have to use another package name, because 'com.example' is limited.

Does anyone know why, or to what, and how I should change this?

If I need to add any screenshots or codes, feel free to ask. Hope some of you can help me out.

Thanks.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Change your package name across the app. com.example is doesn't make much of the scene . it should be like com.your app name. eg. com.tricorder . Must be something unique.

Comment: I see answer is given .  anyway I recommend you to use "Android Studio"   the official IDE from google to develop android apps. eclipse is  no longer   recommend to use for android development.

Comment: I haven't solved it yet tho, as I get the error shown in the edited image. But I heared android studio is much better. will use that for future projects, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your package name, coz package name must be unique.

**To change package name in `Eclipse`**

`Right click` on your project name and select `Android Tools` , then click 
 `Rename Application Package`, then change your project name click `OK` and 
 click `Finish`.

You need to check AndroidManifest.xml whether it is updated correctly or not.

Comment: I changed it to com.informatie.rodekruis, and now i get the error; Failed to create 'link to my project'

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project

Comment: You should consider to move on to `Android Studio` asap.

Comment: Did it, error is gone now. However, when I upload the apk file, that I zip aligned 2 hours ago, it still says that I have com.example, even though I changed it. How do I update my apk file, so that it knows i changed the package name?

Comment: Will do for future projects

Comment: You should generate a new signed apk to upload to Google play.

Comment: So basically zip align my file again? Does that mean I have to do that after every change I make to my project?

Comment: Definitely! You should generate new signed APK every time when you need to upload to Google Play.

Comment: Do you know the fastest way of doing that? I saw a way on youtube, but that took kind of long

Comment: Generate your signed apk only when u upload a new version to Google play. Its not an everyday task.

Comment: Happy to help, If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: But how do i sign it when I did that one hour ago? Cause now I changed something and I need to sign it again.

Comment: Do it again bro! Generate new signed apk AGAIN.

Comment: Yeah did it. App is in Prod-fase right now. Idk how long that will take or what I can do now, but the question is answered and solved by you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own website change it to that. If not either just make one up or head over to hover.com (or similar) and buy a domain.

Comment: I changed it to com.informatie.rodekruis, and now i get the error; Failed to create 'link to my project'